# Zapier conditional loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, zapier

I'm using some Zapier javascript to build an array from daily batches of data returned via an API, so I can create separate records in Airtable from that data.

I'm using an approach documented here: https://community.zapier.com/tips-and-inspiration-5/how-to-repeat-action-s-in-your-zap-for-a-variable-number-of-values-3037

My fields are: FirstName, SecondName, email and phone

```html
/* Add as many Input Data fields as you like above as comma seperated text or mapped line items (will be 
   converted to comma seperated text). This code will find each Input Data field and output an array of 
   objects with the same structure that can be used to "Fork" the Zap. 
   Example: https://cdn.zappy.app/9de81901f3750ef26bcbbd0737b0937b.png */

// get Input Data field names
let keys = Object.keys(inputData)
let data = [];

// loop through each Input Data field
for (let key of keys) {
  // split the contents of each Input Data field on the commas into an array
  let li = inputData[key].split(",");
  for (let i=0; i<li.length; i++) {
    if (typeof data[i] === "undefined") data[i] = {};
    data[i][key] = li[i];
    // add a record number (in case we want to break the fork/loop with a Filter)
    data[i].recordNumber = i+1;
  }
}

// preview the whole data structure in the output
console.log(data);
// output the data
output = data;
```

The main value I need for my Airtable records is an email address, but unfortunately it is is not always present in the source data from the API. I do not need to create an Airtable record at all if the email value is not present.

So I want to modify this script so it will skip any records where `email=null`

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Great question!

It looks like your variable `data` looks like this at the end of the loop:

```js
[{FirstName: 'Richard', SecondName: 'F', email: 'asdf@asdf.com', phone: '123...'}, ...]
```

And then you want to filter that array to remove any objects that lack an email before sending it out into the world.

For that, change the last line to:

```js
output = data.filter(item => item.email)
```

You can play around with this here: https://runkit.com/xavdid/5f1b2445d4a368001b400372